# Can I execute an App Windows UWP generated by Codename One on Windows 10 Desktop machines?

Tags: codenameone

I have a client that needs my App (that was developed using Codename-One-Framework) executing on Windows 10 Desktop machines as well on the Android devices.

My Codename One account allows me to generates Windows UWP Apps.

Can I execute an App Windows UWP generated by Codename One on Windows 10 Desktop machines?

I already tried to do that, bat it didn't work.

Firstly, I generated a Windows-UWP-App and downloaded it on my windows 10 machine.
I unzipped the file that was downloaded and double-clicked on the UWPApp_1.0.1.0_x86 file.
Then,  one dialog box was opened offering an install button.
I clicked on the install button and an evolution bar have been shown but it stops quickly with an error message reporting problems related to lack of some dependencies and suggesting install the .NET-CoreRuntime.1.0.

I provided this installation and tried again.
The same problem and message repeated themselves.

I tried to execute using the powershell command line too.
The result was the same but adding more detailed error messages.

What am I doing wrong?

Click on the link below to see more detailed error messages.

[error messagens](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sreb6xSGPKsu8d5cq8fVl4b6prHd6LGs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: When I try to execute the UWP-App the windows desktop machine launches an exception reporting the installer failed during installing some dependences. I already installed the dot-net-runtime core before the execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can run UWP apps on a desktop but generally you need to deploy them through the Microsoft Store. See the following from the [developer guide UWP section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-uwp.html):

> UWP apps may be deployed directly to Windows 10 desktop and mobile
>   devices without any need to involve the Windows Store. This process is
>   only realistic, though, for testing and debugging your app during
>   development because it requires you to enable "Development" mode on
>   the device. In addition, installation is a little bit more complicated
>   than simply downloading an app over the internet. The process for
>   deploying to Windows 10 desktop devices is different than the process
>   for mobile devices. These are described in the following sections.

Comment: Now, I´m getting the error:
Windows cannot install package XXXXX.com... because this package depends on a
framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0" published by "CN=Microsoft
Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, ...", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and
minimum version 1.0.23819.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name
"Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0" currently installed are: {}

How can I install dotnet-runtime1.0.? I installed dotnet runtime but it isn´t recognized by the power-shell script execution.

Comment: I finally installed my App on my Windows 10 Desktop. I found the DotNET.runtime 1.0 executable and installed it before the execution of Power-Shell script present in the bundle generated by CodeName One builder.  The "script" reports the App was installed successfully.  But,  when I launch the App It aborts immediately with no error message that could explain the reason.

Comment: Did you select "Desktop debug build" in the settings?
Did you follow the instructions about downloading the dependencies from the developer guide?

Comment: Hi. I already solved the problem related to the installation. I added the dependencies and followed the instructions provided by the link you have mentioned here, installed the DotNET.Runtime1.0 provided by Microsoft and finally, the installation happened. But the App didn't work. When I launch the app on my windows 10's machine, the App aborts its execution immediately without no error messages that could explain what could be wrong.

Comment: But did you install the right dependencies from the downloads?